# Mysql blob field using python orator

Tags: python, mysql, database, blob, sql-insert

I'm trying to fill blob column in `MySQL`table using [orator](https://orator-orm.com/) library. Here is python code:

```
self.__db.insert('insert into `classifierinfo` '
                 '(`Name`, `InputFormat`, `NumberOfClasses`, '
                 '`Code`, `ClassifierFile`, `IDClassifierType`) '
                 'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                 ['Классификатор изображений на базе датасета cifar10',
                 '32 32',
                 10,
                 123,
                 open('model.h5', 'rb').read(),
                 1])
```

And the output is:

```
0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\..
```

Return code is 1. So, there is no exceptions or anything else just bytes of the file. What's the problem and how can I fix?

Comment: Did you check if the values are correctly taken in `classifierinfo` ?

Comment: Here is table schema [link](https://c.radikal.ru/c17/1801/4d/21df66ec17cc.png)
I guess everything is right